# apex:actionFunction stopping previous button to show previous screen

Tags: visualforce, visual-workflow, rerender, actionfunction, visual-flows

I have a visualforce page

```
<apex:page controller="ActionFunctionDemoController" >  
    <flow:interview name="Calculator" rerender="ddff" />
    <apex:outputPanel id="ddff" />
    <apex:form >
        <apex:actionFunction name="action1" action="{!action1}" rerender="scriptPanel" />
    </apex:form>
    <apex:outputPanel id="scriptPanel">
        <script>
        var nextBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('FlowNextBtn');
        var j=0;
        for(j=0;j<nextBtns.length;j++) { 
            nextBtns[j].addEventListener('click',function(){
                console.log('--coming here--');
                action1();
            });           
        }
        var previousBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('FlowPreviousBtn');
        for(var j=0;j<previousBtns.length;j++) {
            previousBtns[j].addEventListener('click',function(){
                console.log('--coming here---');
            });
        }
        </script>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:page>
```

and apex controller

```
public with sharing class ActionFunctionDemoController {
    public Pagereference action1() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

my flow definition is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Flow xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <choices>
        <name>Excellent</name>
        <choiceText>Excellent</choiceText>
        <dataType>Number</dataType>
        <value>
            <numberValue>20.0</numberValue>
        </value>
    </choices>
    <choices>
        <name>Fair</name>
        <choiceText>Fair</choiceText>
        <dataType>Number</dataType>
        <value>
            <numberValue>10.0</numberValue>
        </value>
    </choices>
    <choices>
        <name>Good</name>
        <choiceText>Good</choiceText>
        <dataType>Number</dataType>
        <value>
            <numberValue>15.0</numberValue>
        </value>
    </choices>
    <choices>
        <name>Poor</name>
        <choiceText>Poor</choiceText>
        <dataType>Number</dataType>
        <value>
            <numberValue>5.0</numberValue>
        </value>
    </choices>
    <formulas>
        <name>TipAmount</name>
        <expression>{!Bill_Amount}*{!Quality_Of_Service}</expression>
        <scale>2</scale>
    </formulas>
    <formulas>
        <name>TotalBill</name>
        <expression>{!TipAmount}+{!Bill_Amount}</expression>
        <scale>2</scale>
    </formulas>
    <label>Calculator</label>
    <screens>
        <description>Capture bill amount and service quality</description>
        <name>Bill_Information</name>
        <label>Bill Information</label>
        <locationX>435</locationX>
        <locationY>152</locationY>
        <allowBack>true</allowBack>
        <allowFinish>true</allowFinish>
        <connector>
            <targetReference>Show_Tip_Summary</targetReference>
        </connector>
        <fields>
            <name>Bill_Amount</name>
            <dataType>Currency</dataType>
            <fieldText>Bill Amount</fieldText>
            <fieldType>InputField</fieldType>
            <isRequired>true</isRequired>
            <scale>2</scale>
        </fields>
        <fields>
            <name>Quality_Of_Service</name>
            <choiceReferences>Excellent</choiceReferences>
            <choiceReferences>Good</choiceReferences>
            <choiceReferences>Fair</choiceReferences>
            <choiceReferences>Poor</choiceReferences>
            <dataType>Number</dataType>
            <fieldText>Quality Of Service</fieldText>
            <fieldType>RadioButtons</fieldType>
            <isRequired>true</isRequired>
            <scale>2</scale>
        </fields>
    </screens>
    <screens>
        <description>Display tip amount</description>
        <name>Show_Tip_Summary</name>
        <label>Show Tip Summary</label>
        <locationX>789</locationX>
        <locationY>302</locationY>
        <allowBack>true</allowBack>
        <allowFinish>true</allowFinish>
        <fields>
            <name>TipSummary</name>
            <fieldText>You say the quality of service was {!Quality_Of_Service}, so you should leave a tip of  {!TipAmount}
for a total bill of {!TotalBill} .</fieldText>
            <fieldType>DisplayText</fieldType>
        </fields>
    </screens>
    <startElementReference>Bill_Information</startElementReference>
</Flow>
```

in this visualforce page when i click next it will redirect me to next screen but when i click on previous button it doesn't go to previous screen.i tried a lot of things but not able to success.i want when previous button clicked it will show previous screen.please tell why its not showing previous screen ??